# How can I return list of car has name contain string in ArrayList java?

Tags: java

I'm learning `java`. I have trouble when I display a list of the car has name contain string name given? When I return a; list a will display all, it includes car has the name doesn't contain string name. Someone help me please, thank so much. Here is my code and interface.

```
@Override
public List<Car> f1(List<Car> a, String name) {

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
       if(a.get(i).getName().contains(name)){
           System.out.println(a.get(i).getName());
       }
    }
    return a;
}
List<Car> f1(List<Car> a, String name);
```

Comment: Can you share your error?

Comment: When I return a; list a will display all. I just want to output list car contain(String name) in list a

Comment: Put a `break` inside `if` and then return `a.get(i)` if `i < a.size()`

Comment: Inside if statement just store it in `local array` and return that `array` should work

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public List<Car> f1(List<Car> a, String name) {


       for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
       if(a.get(i).getName().contains(name)){
        //   System.out.println(a.get(i).getName());
        return a.get(i);
       }
    }

}
List<Car> f1(List<Car> a, String name);
```

Comment: it will notice error on new List(); List is abstract, cannot be instantiated